# AS#3 changing material Textures

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, away3d

I cant seem to find a solution, anyways basically im trying to add a new dynamic texture to a 3D model using Away3d engine with flash

```
   var myImage:BitmapData = new BitmapData(256, 256, true,0xFFFFFFFF);

   // i cant seem to reference this to my 3D model in the example: Myevent(enter frame):

   myModel.material = new TextureMaterial(new BitmapTexture(myImage))
```

I have tried different things along the above method, i have checked the away3d docs and cant find something similar for my current situation:

Im using the latest Away3d lib, and flash player 11...all my models works and load with there original embedded materialtTextures, im just trying to change them to a bitmap or texture that i have dynamically created

Comment: what error are you gettting?

Comment: damm i thought you had an answer been stuck on this for a day , its driving me insane.... im getting no errors, just my material is not changing , iv tried render(); and updating methods.....nothing working i got no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here:

https://github.com/away3d/away3d-tutorials-fp11/blob/master/tutorials/materials/basic_shading/src/Basic_Shading.as

They use  Away3D’s Cast utility class to create BitmapTexture objects  and they also add a bunch of different texture maps - hopefully this helps

** EDIT --- This Tutorial Does Work **

Added

```
public bmt:BtiMapTexture;

....
private function initMaterials():void {
    this.bmt = new BitmapTexture(new BitmapData(256,256, true, 0x222277FF));
    sphereMaterial = new TextureMaterial(Cast.bitmapTexture(this.bmt));
    sphereMaterial.specularMap = Cast.bitmapTexture(this.bmt);
    sphereMaterial.lightPicker = lightPicker;
}
```

And I got a nice blue sphere

Comment: nah, this doesnt help at all, that example is just loading in images(jpegs) to add to a mesh or objects, where i dont have any jpegs im just trying to make my model material change to the bitmap that i had created  dynamically....

Comment: var myImage:BitmapData = new BitmapData(256, 256, true,0xFFFFFFFF); this is my image that i want on to my model

Comment: Do you need it to be a texture or can you do this with ColorMaterial instead?

Comment: it has to be a texturematerial, i tried using the above, again theres no errors but also nothing is happening... difference is i have an embedded model with a texture on it, then im trying to replace it at runtime

Comment: I got it to work on the tutorial code with what I posted above - see what you have different see if it fixes it - you probably have to use Cast.bitmapTexture()

Comment: var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(256, 256, false,0xFF0000);
var texture:BitmapTexture = new BitmapTexture(bitmapData);    body.material = new TextureMaterial(Cast.bitmapTexture(texture));

Comment: i advertise this on free lancer, for $30-50, i understand what your saying , but im trying to overlay ontop of an existing embedded mesh which already has textures

Comment: can you post your code - I'll look at it and see if I can get it to work

Comment: give me 10 minutes i will upload it all to my server so you have a good idea what im talking about

Comment: view here http://www.parele.com/carhdtest.html  right click view source to view action script

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20362/discussion-between-gone3d-and-parele)

Comment: hey again , i tried your suggestions, it still doesnt take effect, iv contacted the admin for sea3d and still no solution, im guessing im gonna give up on this library, and just use the standard away3d lib...dissapointing but  theres not enough documentation on this format "sea3d"....

Comment: Did you ever run my code as I used it?  I had no problem getting it to work.

Comment: your example is fine, all the tuts online work fine...but theres no examples on loading models meshes and changing there materials at runtime, i have even made a new complete test file with source code:  http://www.parele.com/plane.html

Comment: Then you should accept this answer and ask a new one specifically for the SEA model.  That was the underlying issue and it wasn't until you provided more info that we found it.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
var mesh:Mesh = 'the mesh for changing'
for each (var item:SubMesh in mesh.subMeshes) {
item.material = null;
}
mesh.material = new ColorMaterial(0xFF00FF);
```